# Getting the full path for user folders windows 10

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer, file-shortcut

In Windows 10 when you make shortcuts to folders, like my User folder or Documents, it makes a weird custom shortcut instead.

[image]

[image]

When I click a shortcut made from my user folder from Quick access or anywhere else, it creates a second user folder in the navigation pane.
The "fake" user folder doesn't have my documents folder (among others), and 
the path in the top is just itself.

Documents does the same thing, making a shortcut that leads to This PC < Documents instead of C:\Users\Draykoth\Documents where it should be.

[image]

Is there any way to change this behavior or modify the shortcuts?

Comment: `PC < Documents` and `C:\Users\Draykoth\Documents` are the same path.  What exactly is the problem?

Comment: Usually when I want to go to the documents, I am also there for a lot of other folders within my user folder. With the PC < Documents, I can't press the "one folder up" button, or have any of the surrounding folders in the navigation pane because they're in a different folder path.

Comment: So access the Documents directory from your Desktop which has your Username directory on it.  You are not going to be able to change the behavior of the Documents Quick Access entry, you can add your own entry, but that would duplicate the folder.